# window.location.href is not redirecting html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a form and do some validation using JS. On success I want to redirect it to some other page in the same directory. While running window.location.href over console it is working...but while submitting form, it is not working.

Can someone please help me in this.

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 400px;
  align-self: center;
}

span.psw {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

</style>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Mega Cart</h2>

<form name=loginForm onsubmit="login()" style="display: inline-block;">
 

  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
   
  </div>
    <span class="psw">New user Sign up here. <a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
  </div>
 
</form>

</body>
<script>
    function login() {
      let uname = document.forms["loginForm"]["uname"].value;
      let pwd = document.forms["loginForm"]["psw"].value;
      window.location.href="main.html";
      return false;
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

I have already checked that this login function is called.

Comment: Did you leave off the quotes around `name=loginForm` in real life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the form submit button it call the function `login` in javascript. In which you have write down the code to redirect the page.

You forgot to prevent the form to submit and that is why you are redirecting to the same page with filled-up values.

If you want to submit your form to specific URL then you should add the `action` attribute to the form like below.

`<form name=loginForm action="URL on which you want to submit form" onsubmit="login()" style="display: inline-block;">`

If you want to redirect from the `login()` function then you should pass the event as an argument from the form and then prevent form submission from the `login()` function. Please check the below code.

In your form: `<form name=loginForm onsubmit="login(event)" style="display: inline-block;">`

Change Login function:

```
function login(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let uname = document.forms["loginForm"]["uname"].value;
  let pwd = document.forms["loginForm"]["psw"].value;
  window.location.href="main.html";
}
```

**NOTE! Don't forget to pass `event` in login function**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
window.location.replace('main.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

- In  onsubmit function, you can't redirect the page

First, In your **form** tag, add an action attribute

```
<form name=loginForm onsubmit="login()" action="main.html" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Second, Fixed your **login** function

```
function login() {
      let uname = document.forms["loginForm"]["uname"].value;
      let pwd = document.forms["loginForm"]["psw"].value;
      return false;
    }
```

- Check the redirect URL that contains your data

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 400px;
  align-self: center;
}

span.psw {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

</style>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">The Mega Cart</h2>

<form name=loginForm onsubmit="login()" style="display: inline-block;">
 

  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
    <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
   
  </div>
    <span class="psw">New user Sign up here. <a href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
  </div>
 
</form>

</body>
<script>
    function login() {
      let uname = document.forms["loginForm"]["uname"].value;
      let pwd = document.forms["loginForm"]["psw"].value;
        window.location.href = "https://minisoft.com.bd/"; 
         
      return false;
    }
    
    </script>
</html>
```